# Moving Polyline WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to move a plus symbol for all my program and get the point of the center of the symbol. The plus symbol is a shape and it's in a canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="canvas1_PreviewMouseDown" 
        PreviewMouseMove="canvas1_PreviewMouseMove"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="canvas1_PreviewMouseUp" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,10,0">
        <Polyline Name="myPolyline"
          MouseDown="Polyline_MouseDown"
          Points="25,0 25,50 25,25 0,25 50,25" 
          Stroke="Blue"
          StrokeThickness="2"
          Height="50"/>
    </Canvas>
```

My methods:

```
private void canvas1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if the click was in a chape
        if (e.Source is Shape)
        {
            // Get the mouse position
            start = e.GetPosition(canvas1);
            // Initialize some components and set opacity to 50%
            isDragging = true;
            movedElement = (Shape)e.Source;
            ((Shape)e.Source).Opacity = 0.5;
            canvas1.CaptureMouse();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void canvas1_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            Point Pt = e.GetPosition(canvas1);
            // Get the actual position of the Shape
            double CurrentLeft = (double)movedElement.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
            double CurrentTop = (double)movedElement.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);

            // Calc the new position
            double newLeft = CurrentLeft + Pt.X - start.X;
            double newTop = CurrentTop + Pt.Y - start.Y;

            // Move the element
            movedElement.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newLeft);
            movedElement.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newTop);

            start = Pt;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void canvas1_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Restore the values
        movedElement.Opacity = 1;
        movedElement.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, ++currentZ);
        isDragging = false;
        canvas1.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
```

I found some methods that worked perfectly moving lines, rectangles and ellipses, but my plus symbol is a Polyline, and the methods didn't move it, i belive that the reson is in the line:

`movedElement = (Shape)e.Source;` 
or

`double CurrentLeft = (double)movedElement.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
double CurrentTop = (double)movedElement.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);`

because the GetValue is returning "NaN" and i realy don't know why.I tryed to make the plus symbol using two lines, but was hard to me to move both lines toguether.Can anyone tell me if there is an error in the code or the problem is with the type of my plus symbol?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties in your XAML before you can query them in the code-behind.  They are null by default.  Example:

```
<Polyline Name="myPolyline"
    ...
    Canvas.Left="0"
    Canvas.Top="0"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

*emphasized text*

```
enter code here
    private void canvas2_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //create polyline
        polyline1 = new Polyline();
        polyline1.StrokeThickness = 4;
        polyline1.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        Canvas.SetTop(polyline1, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(polyline1, 0);
    }


    private bool isPolyLine1Drog;
    double mousePosOnPolyline1X;
    double mousePosOnPolyline1Y;
    private void Polyline1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isPolyLine1Drog = true;
        //get distance between current mouse position and top_left polyline
        mousePosOnPolyline1X= e.GetPosition(canvas2).X-Canvas.GetLeft(polyline1);
        mousePosOnPolyline1Y = e.GetPosition(canvas2).Y-Canvas.GetTop(polyline1);
        polyline1.CaptureMouse();
    }
    private void Polyline1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isPolyLine1Drog = false;
        polyline1.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
    private void Polyline1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isPolyLine1Drog) return;
        //top=top+Y changing and left=left+X changing
        double left= e.GetPosition(canvas2).X - mousePosOnPolyline1X;
        double top = e.GetPosition(canvas2).Y - mousePosOnPolyline1Y;
        Canvas.SetLeft(polyline1, left);
        Canvas.SetTop(polyline1, top);
    }//mohsen_seif@yahoo.com
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.